# Create a MySQL stored function with a dynamic number of arguments

Tags: mysql, arguments, user-defined-functions, variadic-functions

I am trying to create a MySQL function `IS_IN_ENUM('value', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')` which return true if 'value' is in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3'). I know I can do `SELECT 'value' IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')` but that's less intersting because I just want to learn how to create such functions.

I give you an example, consider the following `ADD` function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_add (
    a DOUBLE,
    b DOUBLE
)
RETURNS DOUBLE
BEGIN

    IF a IS NULL THEN
        SET a = 0;
    END IF;

    IF b IS NULL THEN
        SET b = 0;
    END IF;

    RETURN (a + b);
END;
```

If I do `SELECT my_add(1, 1)`, I get 2 (wow!).

How can I improve this function to be able to call :

```
SELECT my_add(1, 1); -- 2
SELECT my_add(1, 1, 1); -- 3
SELECT my_add(1, 1, 1, 1); -- 4
SELECT my_add(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, .....); -- n
```

Comment: one question, can't you pass multiple params in one param? `MYFUNCT(('1','2','3'))`?

Comment: You can pass a SET, such as `MYFUNCT("1,2,3")` and then play with the SET-ready functions. But that's not really friendly.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen what would the function create syntax look like for that?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, back in 2015 I was looking at the nodejs mysql library which abstracted away the `VALUES` bit in a pretty cool way and I was under the impression that you'd be able to do it in SQL direct, which figures is not the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function example you show is a *Stored Function*, not a UDF.  Stored Functions in MySQL don't support a variable number of arguments, as @Enzino answered.

MySQL UDFs are written in C or C++, compiled into dynamic object files, and then linked with the MySQL server with a [different syntax of `CREATE FUNCTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-function-udf.html).

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-udf.html for details of writing UDFs.  But I don't know if you want to get into writing C/C++ code to do this.

MySQL UDFs do support variable number of arguments.  In fact, all UDFs implicitly accept any number of arguments, and it's up to you as the programmer to determine if the number and datatypes of the arguments given are valid for your function.

Processing function arguments in UDFs is documented in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/udf-arguments.html

Comment: Nope, I do want to find the MySQL equivalent of the C `varargs`, MySQL does such a function with `CONCAT` for example, which can take as much arguments as we want. If that's possible of course. Thank you for pointing it out the difference between Stored Functions and UDFs, I already read that somewhere but I forgot.

Comment: `CONCAT()` is implemented in C as a built-in function.  There are numerous built-in functions with variable args.  I myself contributed the `SHA2()` function, which supports two arguments, the second of which is optional.  But to do so, it had to be implemented in C.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to create a MySQL function IS_IN_ENUM('value', 'val1',
>   'val2', 'val3') which return true if 'value' is in ('val1', 'val2',
>   'val3').

For this you can use the native function FIELD:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field

IS_IN_ENUM means FIELD != 0.

Check also FIND_IN_SET

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Stored functions do not support variable number of parameters.

Now, if you really want to implement such a native function yourself in the MySQL server code, look for subclasses of `Create_native_func` in `sql/item_create.cc`

Answer (score 0):

Old question but you don need to create is_in_enum since that is already build in. simply do select true from table where value IN (1,2,3,4);